Exibir elemento atual e seguinte de array usando PHP
Faço uma consulta no BD e é exibido uma lista de produtos com as datas da compra.
Cada linha exibi o produto e data da compra.
Gostaria de saber a melhor forma de exibir também na msm linha, o produto do dia seguinte.
FORMA ATUAL
24/01/24 - ARROZ
25/01/24 - MACARRÃO
26/01/24 - FEIJÃO
FORMA QUE PRETENDO FAZER
24/01/24 - ARROZ - MACARRÃO
25/01/24 - MACARRÃO - FEIJÃO
26/01/24 - FEIJÃO
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);   

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM elementos";
$result = $conn->query($consulta);
while($dados = $result->fetch_array()){ 
echo ."DATA :".$dados[0]  ."COMPRA DO DIA : ".$dados[1]."<br>"; 
     echo "</div>";        
}

Eu sei que é simples, mas agradeço qq ajuda.

Você pode fazer isso através de consulta SQL:
select lista_compras_agrupada.data, lista_compras_agrupada.itens, group_concat(lista_compras_amanha.nome separator ' - ') as itens_amanha
from (select `data`, group_concat(nome separator ' - ') as itens from lista_compras group by lista_compras.data) as lista_compras_agrupada
left join lista_compras as lista_compras_amanha on lista_compras_amanha.data = date_add(lista_compras_agrupada.data, interval 1 day)
group by lista_compras_agrupada.data

https://onecompiler.com/mysql/42vrry4n8
